# On MacOS, using homebrew, with or without xquartz, gs segfaults when trying to open a postscript file

Tags: macos, homebrew, x11, ghostscript, postscript

On MacOS, M1 chip, homebrew, don't want to use Preview.

gs -q -sDEVICE=display The_Swan.ps
zsh: segmentation fault  gs -q -sDEVICE=display

Using gs without -q and without -s results in a GS> prompt.

I just want to display the postscript file.

Thanks,
Ken

Comment: Try typing just showpage at the GS> prompt, what happens ? Other than that your best bet is probably to open a bug report.

Comment: It's also worth trying a different device, just to see if it works. Try "-sDEVICE=tiff24nc -o out.tif". If that works then it's something specific to the display device, which varies depending on how the binary was built.

Comment: gs ./four_octave_scale.ps
GPL Ghostscript 9.56.1 (2022-04-04)
Copyright (C) 2022 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
%%BoundingBox: 64 150152 567 150958
%%HiResBoundingBox: 64.817998 150152.053418 566.945983 150957.751393
>>showpage, press <return> to continue<<
showpage
GS>%%BoundingBox: 0 0 0 0
%%HiResBoundingBox: 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
>>showpage, press <return> to continue<<

Comment: gs -sDEVICE=tiff24nc -o out.tif ./four_octave_scale.ps
GPL Ghostscript 9.56.1 (2022-04-04)
Copyright (C) 2022 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
source: file out.tif
out.tif: TIFF image data, little-endian, direntries=20, height=792, bps=270, compression=none, PhotometricIntepretation=RGB, orientation=upper-left, width=612

Comment: So it seems like those work, it's just the display device you are having trouble with. I don't have an M1 Mac to try this on. I think there's one around somewhere I can ask someone to try though, but first I'll try it on a regular Intel Mac.

Comment: I've tried this on MacOS, built from source (I am not a Mac user and know nothing about homebrew). configure reports I have X available and the display device is available after build, and works as expected. It sounds to me like there is some incompatibility between your system and the homebrew binary. I can only suggest you build Ghostscript from source instead.

Comment: It must be a problem with not having an X envioronment active (?) But I don't know how to get one running, I have xquartz, but apparently it is not running? Without X Windows, it looks like gs is not meant for viewing postscript files.

Comment: The display device on Unix-like OS's does depend on having an X server, yes. If your binary has been built for X, and you don't have X installed, then it certainly won't work, I guess it might crash, I'm not certain. Viewing PostScript files is only a very small part of what Ghostscript is used for. I can't offer any advice on XQuartz. You could either build a viewer yourself and use the memory buffer from GS to draw the content, render to a file format and view that, or install Windows or Linux in a VM and view the file there.

Comment: On the homebrew GitHub discussion list it was stated that the gs binary does not have support for X Windows.  So I have closure now :-(

Comment: You can always build Ghostscript from source yourself.

Comment: Yes, I could build ghostscript (and ghostview) from source linking to X Windows libraries...I'm a little too old for that now :-) But I might try it...

Comment: I noticed that homebrew ghostscript was updated to 10.00; I upgraded; started xquartz; ran gs with a pdf file; same behavior as previous.  I guess I needed to log out after starting xquartz, but I've got too much pending stuff to log out at this time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the `-sDEVICE=display`. <del>I don't think there's actually a device available by that name.</del> If you simply leave off the `-sDEVICE=` argument altogether the default device will be the appropriate display device for your system (assuming ghostscript was installed using a package manager for your system).

You only need to specify a device if it's something other than the default.

On my installation, the default device is: `x11alpha`. `gs --help` will tell you what the default is on your installation.

Comment: If there's no display device then you will get an error saying so if you try to select it (or you should!), so it isn't that, sorry.

Comment: Oh, I see it now in the list. I'm leaning towards the bug hypothesis. I get the same result with gs 9.55.0 on Cygwin.

Comment: Well the current version is 9.56.1, if you see a problem with that we'd welcome a bug report. Ideally not with Cygwin though :-(

Answer (score 0):

I confirm this issue on my M1 mac. I also just downloaded and built the latest release candidate of ghostscript v10, and it's working great on the same system. Until it's officially released, you need to download the source from https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/tag/gs10.0.0rc1 unpack the .tar.xz, `cd` into that directory, `./configure` then `make` and after about 5 minutes, you'll have a new `gs` executable in the `bin` subdirectory. I tried repeating the experiment that crashed gs v9.56.1 and it worked fine with v10.0.0rc1. I imagine there will be a full official release soon. When that happens, I'll update this answer.

Interestingly (to me) the *default* behavior of gs v10 is to open a display window.